# How to sum up individual columns if they have the same value in a different column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following data frame:

```
            Names      Counts  Year
0           Jordan        1043  2000
1            Steve         204  2000
2            Brock           3  2000
3            Steve          33  2000
4             Mike          88  2000
...           ...         ...   ...
20001        Bryce           2  2015
20002        Steve          11  2015
20003        Penny          24  2015
20004        Steve          15  2015
20005        Penny           5  2015
```

I want to add up all the counts for each name if they appear multiple times in a year.
An example of the output might look like:

```
            Names      Counts  Year
0           Jordan        1043  2000
1            Steve         237  2000
2            Brock           3  2000
3             Mike          88  2000
...           ...         ...   ...
20001        Bryce           2  2015
20002        Steve          26  2015
20003        Penny          29  2015
```

I've tried the following:

```
(df[df['Names'].eq('Steve')].groupby('Year').agg({'Names': 'first', 'Counts': sum}).reset_index())
```

Which returns the following for individual names, but it's not what I'm looking for.

```
   Year  Names  Counts
0  2000  Steve     237
1  2015  Steve      26
```

Comment: you're filtering the dataset with Steve and its getting summed up per your expected output. what you find is incorrect here?

Comment: Please read the question. I give an example output of what I expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
df['Counts'] = df.groupby(['Names','Year'])['Counts'].transform('sum')
```

Answer (score 0):

The code that you shared looks like it is filtering the "Names" column for only the value "Steve".
The below code will group the unique pairs of "Name" & "Year" combinations and sum all related "Counts" values.

```
tempdf = df.groupby(['Names',"Year"])['Counts'].sum().reset_index()
```